# How to use pybind11 to convert between Eigen::Quaternion and numpy ndarray

Tags: c++, eigen3, pybind11

I am trying to wrap up a c++ function that takes in Eigen::Quaternion as the argument for python usage.
The function is defined as something like:

```
void func(const Eigen::Quaternion<double> &rotation) {...}
```

I am using pybind11 to wrap it for python and in my pybind11 I have:

```
#include <pybind11/eigen.h> // I have this included

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    m.def("func", &func, "example function");
}
```

Everything looks good, it compiles, but when I call it by:

```
func(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]))
```

I got error:

> func(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types
> are supported: 1. (arg0: Eigen::Quaternion<double,0>) -> None

Did some googling and could not find an answer regarding if Eigen::Quaternion can be casted to/from numpy array and what shape of the array should be used? I thought Quaternion can be just casted from a 4 element numpy ndarray but seem it is not, any one knows how to do that?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this back then?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found is adding a small C++ wrapper converting `Eigen::Matrix` to `Eigen::Quaternion` like so:

```cpp
void func(const Eigen::Quaternion<double> &rotation) {...}
```

```cpp
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>

void func_wrapper(Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> quat)
{
   func(Eigen::Quaternion<double>(q(0), q(1), q(2), q(3)));
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    m.def("func", &func_wrapper, "example function");
}
```

`func(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]))` should work!

Answer (score -2):

I think the issue is that eigen quat needs doubles and you have constructed your np.array with ints.

```
func(np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]))
```

will probably work?